# Varchar to Date or Timestamp in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column `date_sent` which is in varchar format. I want to capture only date.

```
select
date_sent,
TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(date_sent,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') send_ts,

send_ts::date as send_date
```

tried `TO_DATE(date_sent)` `send_ts` as well but got error:

> Date '1/6/2022 6:01:00 PM' is not recognized

output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since timestamp in varchar format you can capture the date part with the following

```
select substr(date_sent,1,position(' ',ts))::date
```

Example :

```
with data as (select '1/6/2022 6:01:00 PM' date_sent)
select substr(date_sent,1,position(' ',date_sent))::date dt
from data
```

returns

`2022-01-06`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use to_date func and covert:

```
with tbl as (select '1/6/2022 6:01:00 PM'::varchar dt)
select TO_date(dt, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss PM')::date dt
from tbl;
```